# Visual Studio Server Explorer Azure - Missing Reference

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-sdk-.net

So I had to downgrade the Azure SDK from 2.8 to 2.5 to accommodate a project I'm working on.

After doing so, I can't access Azure Storage from Visual Studio 2013. Every time I right click, attach external storage I get a missing assembly (**Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage Version 6.0.0.0**)

The 2.5 SDK comes with **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage Version 4.2**

Is there any way I can manually add/change reference for it to point to the 4.2 dll?

Also, I'm running Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 - v2.5

[image: Error]

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you didn't do this when you downgraded, you can try uninstalling everything from the Azure SDK - simple way to do this is to "search" in control panel for anything containing "Azure" (the names change occasionally so browsing the list is tricky) and there are a lot of MSIs.  After that's clean, reinstall the 2.5 SDK.

Alternatively, if you just need easy access to storage, you might be able to use: http://storageexplorer.com/ instead of server explorer.  I would try the uninstall/reinstall approach first since you may run into other problems if things aren't installed correctly...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did try it out and had the same issue. I also tried storageexplorer but it still doesn't have functionality for tables/queues

Comment: Are you trying to create a new project?  Or redirect a project that was created on 2.8 to 2.5?